# Pandas reindex dates in Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, reindex

I have a dataframe with sporadic dates as the index, and columns = 'id' and 'num'.  I would like to `pd.groupby` the 'id' column, and apply the reindex to each group in the dataframe.

My sample dataset looks like this:

```
            id  num
2015-08-01  1   3
2015-08-05  1   5
2015-08-06  1   4
2015-07-31  2   1
2015-08-03  2   2
2015-08-06  2   3
```

My expected output once `pd.reindex` with `ffill` is:

```
            id  num
2015-08-01  1   3
2015-08-02  1   3
2015-08-03  1   3
2015-08-04  1   3
2015-08-05  1   5
2015-08-06  1   4
2015-07-31  2   1
2015-08-01  2   1
2015-08-02  2   1
2015-08-03  2   2
2015-08-04  2   2
2015-08-05  2   2
2015-08-06  2   3
```

I have tried this, among other things to no avail:
`newdf=df.groupby('id').reindex(method='ffill')` 
Which returns error:`AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'reindex' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method`

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There's probably a slicker way to do this but this works:

```
def reindex_by_date(df):
    dates = pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max())
    return df.reindex(dates).ffill()

df.groupby('id').apply(reindex_by_date).reset_index(0, drop=True)
```

Comment: This works.  Awesome job.  It does take a little while but I can't imagine there is a quicker more pythonic way to do this.  Thanks a ton.

Comment: A slightly different flavor is to write the return part of the function as  `return df.resample('D').fillna(method='ffill') `. This has the added advantage of changing the 'D' in the resample part to 'B' if you only want business days for example (of course this depends on what you want).

Comment: Are you sure that works `Pilik` because I initially tried `resample` but it didn't add in the missing days?  You can achieve different periods like business days in `pd.date_range` as well, e.g. `pd.date_range(.., offset='B')` for business days.

Comment: @JoeCondron, you're right, I didn't know `pd.date_range` had an offset option. I copied the example using `pd.read_clipboard()` and my solution with `resample` also yields the desired result.

Comment: This solution does not work for me: all the rows become `NaN`. If I change function to use  `df.reindex(dates, method = 'ffill')` it gives me `TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'str'`

Comment: @giac_man It sounds as though you have date-like strings in your index. `DatetimIndex` will look identical to an index containing strings of the form `'YYYY-MM-DD'`. You can convert using `pd.to_datetime`