# calcualte numpy IRR with inconsistent frequencies across pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas-groupby, irr

My questions is not around how to calculate *IRR (internal rate of return)* but rather given a data set similar to the below, how to best calculate *IRR* without waiting months for the result when the sample size dramatically increases.

I am using the `np.irr` [function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.irr.html)

### Example of Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

date_list =['2018-01-01', '2018-01-02', '2018-01-03', '2018-01-04','2018-01-05', '2018-01-06', '2018-01-07', '2018-01-14','2018-01-21', '2018-01-31','2018-02-08', '2018-02-28']
ids_list = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]
flows_list = [ -10, 2, 2, 10, -50, 25, 20, 20, -100, 0,  3, 150]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(date_list,ids_list,flows_list)), columns=['Date','ID','Flow'])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

*Yields the Below Dataset*

```
In [144]: df
Out[144]:
         Date  ID  Flow
0  2018-01-01   1   -10
1  2018-01-02   1     2
2  2018-01-03   1     2
3  2018-01-04   1    10
4  2018-01-05   2   -50
5  2018-01-06   2    25
6  2018-01-07   2    20
7  2018-01-14   2    20
8  2018-01-21   3  -100
9  2018-01-31   3     0
10 2018-02-08   3     3
11 2018-02-28   3   150
```

**Data Explanation**

1. `Date` is the day the cash flowed in or out.
2. `ID` is essentially the unique id of each investment made.
3. `Flow` is the cash flow of that `ID` (investment).
4. I need use a **daily frequency** as my input for `np.irr`

**IF I do a simple `pandas.groupby`**

```
In [145]: df.groupby(['ID'])['Flow'].agg(np.irr)
Out[145]:
ID
1    0.141962
2    0.150155
3    0.153450
Name: Flow, dtype: float64
```

**So for `ID` 1 the `np.irr` returned makes sense as my frequency is consistent.**

However, for the rest you'll see the dates are not equally spaced by day.

**Example of 'Manually' calculating `np.irr` for ID 3**

```
df.loc[df.ID ==3]['Date'].apply(lambda x: (x - min(df.loc[df.ID ==3]['Date'])).days)

8      0
9     10
10    18
11    38
Name: Date, dtype: int64
```

Can see above that each cashflow occurs at the beginning, on the 10th, 18th & Finally on the 38th day.

```
cfs = np.zeros(39)
cfs[[0,10,18,38]] = df.loc[df.ID ==3]['Flow'].values

np.irr(cfs)
```

This yields the **actual** `np.irr` for `ID` 3:

```
Out[155]: 0.011386397119650837
```

### So my question is:

> How to calculate `np.irr` across a `pandas.DataFrame` where the cashflow frequencies are inconsistent in an **optimal** manner ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be the most *optimal* and accurate way I could find. Avoiding for loops!!

**Load Example Data**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

date_list =['2018-01-01', '2018-01-02', '2018-01-03', '2018-01-04','2018-01-05', '2018-01-06', '2018-01-07', '2018-01-14','2018-01-21', '2018-01-31','2018-02-08', '2018-02-28']
ids_list = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3]
flows_list = [ -10, 2, 2, 10, -50, 25, 20, 20, -100, 0,  3, 150]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(date_list,ids_list,flows_list)), columns=['Date','ID','Flow'])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

**Re-index data frame to include 0's cashflows**

```
def reindex_by_date_and_fill(df,groupby_column='ID',value_column='Flow'):
    dates = pd.date_range(df.index.min(), df.index.max())
    return pd.concat([df.reindex(dates)[groupby_column].ffill(),df.reindex(dates,fill_value=0)[value_column]],axis=1)

df_test = df.set_index(['Date']).groupby(['ID'],as_index=False).apply(reindex_by_date_and_fill).reset_index(0,drop=True)
```

I got this idea from the below two posts:

[Add missing dates to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19324453/add-missing-dates-to-pandas-dataframe)

[Pandas reindex dates in Groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275540/pandas-reindex-dates-in-groupby)

Basically it fills in the days which are missing and populates the cash flow as a zero. This allows you to get a daily frequency across each investment while still maintaining the period in which the cash flows were paid back.

```
In [54]: df_test.head(10)
Out[54]:
             ID  Flow
2018-01-01  1.0   -10
2018-01-02  1.0     2
2018-01-03  1.0     2
2018-01-04  1.0    10
2018-01-05  2.0   -50
2018-01-06  2.0    25
2018-01-07  2.0    20
2018-01-08  2.0     0
2018-01-09  2.0     0
2018-01-10  2.0     0
```

> This Allows you then to use `groupby`

```
In [60]: df_test.groupby(['ID'])['Flow'].agg(np.irr)
Out[60]:
ID
1.0    0.141962
2.0    0.082212
3.0    0.011386
Name: Flow, dtype: float64
```