# How to resample a Time Series for a specific timerange for each group in a dataframe?

Tags: python, time-series, pandas-resample

I have the following dataframe:

| date | group | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | A | 12 | 2 |
| 2020-02-01 | A | 11 | 4 |
| 2020-03-01 | A | 7 | 5 |
| 2020-04-01 | A | 23 | 3 |
| 2020-03-01 | B | 66 | 1 |
| 2020-04-01 | B | 61 | 8 |
| 2020-06-01 | B | 55 | 8 |
| 2020-04-01 | C | 3 | 0 |
| 2020-06-01 | C | 22 | 112 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I am able to fill the missing dates in between dates per group:

```
df.set_index('date').groupby('group').resample('MS').asfreq().drop(['group'], 1).reset_index()
```

But I want to fill all the dates per group for a specific time range (e.g. 2020-01-01 to 2020-06-01).

So the result would look something like that:

| date | group | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | A | 12 | 2 |
| 2020-02-01 | A | 11 | 4 |
| 2020-03-01 | A | 7 | 5 |
| 2020-04-01 | A | 23 | 3 |
| 2020-05-01 | A | 0 | 0 |
| 2020-06-01 | A | 0 | 0 |
| 2020-01-01 | B | 0 | 0 |
| 2020-02-01 | B | 0 | 0 |
| 2020-03-01 | B | 66 | 1 |
| 2020-04-01 | B | 61 | 8 |
| 2020-05-01 | B | 0 | 0 |
| 2020-06-01 | B | 55 | 8 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Comment: As a start, part of your answer will likely involve `.fillna(0)` if you want `0` instead of `NaN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to follow this [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32275705/13386979) and create a function and `apply` it to each group.  You can set a vector of dates to use for reindexing, and put that into a function which will be applied to each group:

```
START = '01-01-2020'
END = '06-01-2020'
DATE_RANGE = pd.date_range(START, END, freq='MS')

def apply_reindex(df):
    reindexed = df.set_index('date').reindex(DATE_RANGE)
    filled = reindexed.fillna({'group':df.name, 'value1':0, 'value2':0})
    filled.index.name = 'date'
    filled = filled.reset_index()
    return filled
```

There's some annoying index setting/renaming stuff to be able to call reindex on the `date` column and then return it to be a column.

You can then call the function with:

```
df.groupby('group').apply(apply_reindex).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Which produces:

```
        date group  value1  value2
0  2020-01-01     A    12.0     2.0
1  2020-02-01     A    11.0     4.0
2  2020-03-01     A     7.0     5.0
3  2020-04-01     A    23.0     3.0
4  2020-05-01     A     0.0     0.0
5  2020-06-01     A     0.0     0.0
6  2020-01-01     B     0.0     0.0
7  2020-02-01     B     0.0     0.0
8  2020-03-01     B    66.0     1.0
9  2020-04-01     B    61.0     8.0
10 2020-05-01     B     0.0     0.0
11 2020-06-01     B    55.0     8.0
12 2020-01-01     C     0.0     0.0
13 2020-02-01     C     0.0     0.0
14 2020-03-01     C     0.0     0.0
15 2020-04-01     C     3.0     0.0
16 2020-05-01     C     0.0     0.0
17 2020-06-01     C    22.0   112.0
```

Comment: This works great - thank you.
Can you tell me what the df.name in: "filled = reindexed.fillna({'group':df.name})" does?

Comment: @SqHu Sure!  Within the `apply` of a function during a `groupby` operation, the DataFrame that is passed to the function will have its `name` attribute set according to the group it is part of.  So since I am grouping by the `group` column, three DataFrames are passed to the function, and they either have a `.name` of `'A'`, `'B'`, or `'C'`.  I basically just use that to fill any missing values produced by the reindexing for the `group` column.