# Pandas reindex date index by group revisited

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by, reindex

This has been asked before and a working solution has been proposed here [Pandas reindex dates in Groupby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32275540/pandas-reindex-dates-in-groupby), which worked for me in the past, but it does not work any more.

So, to recap I need to reindex dataframe using date to create 'balanced panel' - not to have missing Date-Value combination in any Group. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

date1 = datetime.strptime('2023-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d').date()
date2 = datetime.strptime('2023-01-02', '%Y-%m-%d').date()
date3 = datetime.strptime('2023-01-03', '%Y-%m-%d').date()

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[date1] * 3 + [date2]  + [date3] * 3,
'Group':['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
'Value':[20, 10, 23, 45, 60, 14, 25]})
 
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

Desired output is:

```
df_target = pd.DataFrame({'Date':[date1] * 3 + [date2] * 3  + [date3] * 3,
'Group':['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
'Value':[20, 10, 23, 45, 0, 0, 60, 14, 25]})

df_target.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
```

Attempted solution (note the assertion):

```
def reindex_by_date(df, freq):
    dates = pd.date_range(start=df.index.min(), end=df.index.max(), freq=freq)
    idx = pd.Index(dates, name='Dates')
    assert dates.duplicated().sum()==0
    return df.reindex(dates, fill_value=0)

df.groupby('Group').apply(reindex_by_date(df, freq='D'))

# this has also been added: .reset_index(drop=True)
```

Produces an error:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

I even checked the flags (here it is `True`):

```
df.flags.allows_duplicate_labels
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling the function incorrectly in `apply` (you don't pass the group but rather the whole DataFrame).

This should be:

```
df.groupby('Group').apply(lambda g: reindex_by_date(g, freq='D'))
```

Or:

```
df.groupby('Group').apply(reindex_by_date, freq='D')
```

Output:

```
                 Group  Value
Group                        
A     2023-01-01     A     20
      2023-01-02     A     45
      2023-01-03     A     60
B     2023-01-01     B     10
      2023-01-02     0      0
      2023-01-03     B     14
C     2023-01-01     C     23
      2023-01-02     0      0
      2023-01-03     C     25
```

Note that you'll have to drop `Group` and `reset_index` to avoid the reindexing with 0 in `Group` as column:

```
(df.groupby('Group').apply(reindex_by_date, freq='D')
   .drop(columns='Group').reset_index('Group')
 .rename_axis('Date')
)
```

Output:

```
           Group  Value
Date                   
2023-01-01     A     20
2023-01-02     A     45
2023-01-03     A     60
2023-01-01     B     10
2023-01-02     B      0
2023-01-03     B     14
2023-01-01     C     23
2023-01-02     C      0
2023-01-03     C     25
```

Comment: Dang, the pesky df. typo... Thanks, I see now in my old codes that I was dropping the group column down below. I will keep the question tho, I think it is useful to have it here

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(
    [df.index.unique(), df["Group"].unique()],
    names=["Date", "Group"]
)

out = (
    df
    .set_index("Group", append=True)
    .reindex(idx, fill_value=0)
    .reset_index(level=1)
)
```

out:

```
           Group  Value
Date
2023-01-01     A     20
2023-01-01     B     10
2023-01-01     C     23
2023-01-02     A     45
2023-01-02     B      0
2023-01-02     C      0
2023-01-03     A     60
2023-01-03     B     14
2023-01-03     C     25
```

Comment: This works, thank you! I will wait a bit, perhaps there is a solution with the previous approach and an explanation why 'the old way' is not working the way I implemented it. If it is simply a bug, and there is no way to make previous approach, I will report the bug and accept your answer. The 'old way' was more intuitive to me.